# How to accumulate running totals with constant amounts?

Tags: forms, visual-studio

I am doing an assignment for my class and I'm a supeeeer beginner at coding.  This assignment calls for me to select services and a discount rate and then show them in a total text box beneath the two.

My issue is, I'm supposed to be able to select multiple services and have them total together, but I just can't figure it out.  I'll post the code below:

```
Public Class Form1

Dim CurrentServicesDec As Decimal
Dim CurrentServicesTotal As Decimal
Private DiscountServicesDec As Decimal



Private Sub CalculateButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CalculateButton.Click
    'Calculate the Service(s) selected and add the discount if any.

    If MakeOverCheckBox.Checked = True Then
        CurrentServicesDec = 125

    ElseIf Val(HairStylingCheckBox.Checked) = True Then
        CurrentServicesDec = 60

    ElseIf Val(ManicureCheckBox.Checked) = True Then
        CurrentServicesDec = 35

    ElseIf Val(MakeupCheckbox.Checked) = True Then
        CurrentServicesDec = 200
    End If
    If (TenPercentRadio.Checked) = True Then
        DiscountServicesDec = 0.1
    ElseIf TwentyPercentRadio.Checked = True Then
        DiscountServicesDec = 0.2


    End If

    CurrentServicesTotal = CurrentServicesDec - (CurrentServicesDec * DiscountServicesDec)

    txtTotal.Text = FormatCurrency(CurrentServicesTotal)



End Sub

Private Sub ClearButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ClearButton.Click
    'Clear the options on the form.

    txtTotal.Text = ""
    TenPercentRadio.Checked = False
    TwentyPercentRadio.Checked = False

End Sub

Private Sub ExitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitButton.Click
    'Close the program

    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub PrintButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PrintButton.Click
    'Print Preview the Form

    PrintForm1.PrintAction = Printing.PrintAction.PrintToPreview
    PrintForm1.Print()
End Sub
End Class
```

This is what I have, as far as the program being able to select one service and add the discount, it works perfectly but not for multiple services selected!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your program flow has some issues to get your intended behavior, since with your If block starting with `If MakeOverCheckBox.Checked = True Then`, using `ElseIf` for subsequent branches will cause them to skip.

You're also just assigning the value of `CurrentServicesDec` when I think you should be adding it together - so declare the variable inside your Calculate function and then use `+=`.

So to get the behavior of checking for multiples in your checkbox control - change the `ElseIf` to `If` blocks.

```
Private Sub CalculateButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CalculateButton.Click
Dim CurrentServicesDec As Decimal
If MakeOverCheckBox.Checked = True Then
    CurrentServicesDec += 125
End If

If HairStylingCheckBox.Checked = True Then
    CurrentServicesDec += 60
End If

If ManicureCheckBox.Checked = True Then
    CurrentServicesDec += 35
End If

If MakeupCheckbox.Checked = True Then
    CurrentServicesDec += 200
End If
```

Comment: Alright, I changed the Else If to If, but still the same results.. Thank you for the speedy reply!

Comment: @VomitingWinter not sure what you were doing with your `Val()` calls but I think they are unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah I realized that they were totally unnecessary, just trying to see if it changed anything.  Which it didn't :/

Comment: @VomitingWinter edited the answer a bit to address further issues.

Comment: IT WORKS!  My friend, I would indeed kiss your shiny metal ass right now.